# How to compare two columns in two different tables in SQL?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have two tables. Table A and Table B. How can I compare a column in A (data type: date)
with a column in B (data type: date) with condition: column in B >= column in A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things being asked here.

1) Show me those that are greater

2) Tell me the comparison

So, to do both, try this. Part (1) is in the where clause, and part (2) is in the select statement.

```
select *, datediff(day, b.col, a.col) as ColumnDifference
from TableA a, TableB b
where b.col >= a.col
```

Documentation for datediff: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794(v=sql.100).aspx

Comment: thanks, this is my first time and my english is not good so i couldn't explain more informations.